# How to retrieve the values for only one table field in Django

Tags: python, django

If I have following database fields: `id, name, emp_id`.

How do I make a query in Django to get the values of column `name` only with a where clause.

Thanks...

Comment: Seriously, is there some reason why you can't read the documentation?

Comment: The question title should be better too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try to be be more specific in the future. djangoproject.com and djangobook.com are great resources for help

Comment: K I will be more specific next time.Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, you could also use `values_list` to get the names in a flat list (instead of a dictionary).

```
Model.objects.filter(...).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

See the [documentation for `values_list`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list-fields).

Answer (score 7):

```
Model.objects.filter(...).values('name')
```